# Bootstrap red list text not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a red "X" next to items in a list as a link to delete the item.

I have read I can make the text red using helper classes in bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/regions/91">Wales</a>
    <span class="text-danger">
      <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/regions/91" rel="nofollow">X</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul
```

Comment: Regardless of color, I highly recommend using the unicode `&#215;` =  `&times;` = `×` instead of the regular X letter. It just look better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `text-danger` class to the `<a>` tag itself.

Like this (Option 1):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/regions/91">Wales</a>
    <a class="text-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/regions/91" rel="nofollow">X</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or this (Option 2):

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="/regions/91">Wales</a>
     <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/regions/91" rel="nofollow">
         <span class="text-danger">X</span>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Here is a fiddle for both options](http://jsfiddle.net/jt28gpyx/1/)

Comment: In this case, something is overriding your class. Because if you take a look in the provided fiddle it works. I'll add an another option.

Comment: Option 2 works! Now to work out how to get this into a RoR link_to tag. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rc74c3a1/)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/regions/91">Wales</a>
        <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/regions/91" rel="nofollow"><span class="text-danger">X</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Has to do with the order in which you had everything organized. The anchor tag has CSS being applied which override the css your `span` tag. By reversing them, we're applying the anchor styling, and then the `text-danger`.